# How do I create a class that inherits methods from two other classes and shares own and their methods back to them

Tags: python, class, inheritance, instance, parent-child

So I am trying to do something along the lines of the following in Python 2.7:

```
class Print(object)
    def __init__(self):
        self.printer = 'something'

    def pretty_print(self, text):
        print('Pretty {}'.format(text))

class Report(object)
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 1
        self.var2 = 2

    def return_sum(self):
        return self.var1 + self.divide_by_two(self.var1 + self.var2)



class MasterClass(Report, Print):
    def __init__(self):
        Report.__init__(self)
        Print.__init__(self)
        self.execute()

    def execute(self):
        sum = self.return_sum()

    def divide_by_two(self, number):
        return number / 2
```

So dilemma here is such I want both the Report class and Print class to be able to access methods and variables from MasterClass. Can I do that somehow?

Comment: Classes do no "share methods back" to their base classes.

Comment: *"I want both the Report class and Print class to be able to access methods and variables from MasterClass. Can I do that somehow?"* Yes, of course you can. Just access them; it'll work. What's the problem?

Comment: Is there any workaround at all?

Comment: and the problem is pylint complains that the child class does not have any methods from the parent class defined. Instantiating them would cause another MRO error.

Comment: Methods from `Report` and `Print` can access `MasterClass` methods *if* they are invoked by instances of `MasterClass`. From a *design* standpoint, neither `Report` nor `Print` should rely on methods introduced by subclasses, though. For example, `divide_by_two` could be an abstract method first defined by `Report`, then overriden by `MasterClass`.

Comment: Your design seems a bit off, but try with `Print.__subclasses__()[0].__dict__`.

Comment: I am happy to hear an alternative suggestion here to be honest. Thing Is I have a few classes which is responsible for certain things, for instance generating and sending reports to email, gathering some data, etc. I am not sure whats good here to have a master class execute everything or just trigger one class that inherits another etc. Open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution that worked in this case was carefully planned inheritance and class initializations:

```
class Print(object)

class Report(Print)

class MasterClass(Report)
```